# Confusión sobre el significado _real_ de "ya que": ¿explicación, causa y condición?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, expresiones

Llevo años pensando que sabía que significaba 'ya que'.  A mi entender era más o menos sinónimo de 'porque'.  Pero hace unos días una profesora particular me dijo que no es así, sino que aunque se puede usar 'porque' cada vez que se usa 'ya que',  *no* se puede usar 'ya que' siempre que uses 'porque'.  Además, que 'ya que' contiene un 'aspecto' del inglés 'provided that', o sea, que es más sinónimo de 'en vista de'.  Decía que esto es un matiz, que a todos los efectos *son* sinónimos, pero ahora quedo confundido.  No he podido encontrar mucho sobre el tema, ni en el DPD, tampoco en la red.  He encontrado [este enlace](https://www.practicaespanol.com/el-uso-de-ya-que/) donde se mantiene que

> Con “ya que” introducimos la causa, explicación, y también la condición de algo.

Bien, pero no entiendo, conceptualmente, lo que se quiere decir: ¿causa, explicación *y* condición a la vez?

¿Alguien puede explicármelo un poco mejor, o sea, de manera distinta? Similarmente, ¿qué significa exactamente 'ya que' exactamente, si no es sinónimo de 'porque'?, ya que parece que no lo entiendo perfectamente.  Enlaces a explicaciones en la red (o en alguna referencia) agradecidos.  ¡Gracias por cualquier pista!

Comment: No tengo claro que "ya que" equivalga a "provided that". Yo diría más "seeing that", o "given that", o "since". La conjunción "provided that" expresa cierta incertidumbre: "we will celebrate your graduation, provided that the restrictions at that time allow it": "Celebraremos tu graduación, suponiendo que las restricciones de ese momento lo permitan".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Ya que” es sinónimo de “porque”, pero no un sinónimo exacto. Cuando usamos  “porque”, muchas veces queremos expresar una implicación directa: A porque B. “Te pregunto esto porque me dio curiosidad.” No tendría sentido decir “Te pregunto esto”, partiendo de la nada, si no sigue una explicación inmediatamente después con “porque”.

En cambio, “ya que” es una explicación o aclaración posterior. “Estoy preocupado, ya que no respondiste mis mails en toda la semana.” La segunda parte es una explicación pero no está presentada como implicación. Uno podría decir “Estoy preocupado” y nada más. Lo que viene después, en este caso, es solamente una aclaración.

“Porque” generalmente une dos proposiciones sin una pausa entre las dos. “Ya que” generalmente introduce una pausa, y en la escritura se muestra la pausa [con una coma](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/coma-antes-de-ya-que-pues-o-puesto-que/).

Al comienzo de una oración casi siempre se utiliza “ya que”, casi nunca “porque”. Técnicamente es correcto decir algo como “Porque me importa tu salud, te recomiendo que respetes la cuarentena”, pero en la realidad casi nadie lo diría de esta manera sino con la explicación al final.

Otro uso de “ya que” donde no se puede reemplazar con “porque” es para introducir una circunstancia, similar al inglés *since*. “Ya que vas a venir a casa, podrías traerme los libros que te presté.” En este caso no hay implicación ni aclaración; simplemente se está comunicando una circunstancia temporal. Esto se hace mucho con imperativos: “Ya que no estás haciendo nada ahora, ven a ayudarme con esto.”